# In Unity how do you know if OnTriggerEnter occurred in script A and then increment a value in Script B because of it?

Tags: triggers, unity-game-engine

I am making a multiplayer game and I have a score script attached to the player, so when that player enters a sphere with a collider, it increments a value in his script.

Sorry if this doesn't make any sense.

this is the sphere code

```
function OnTriggerEnter(other : Collider){
Debug.Log("Trigger Entered");
renderer.enabled = false;
collider.isTrigger = false;
collider.enabled = false;
//yield WaitForSeconds ( Random.Range(1.0, 10.0));
yield WaitForSeconds (3);
renderer.enabled = true;
collider.isTrigger = true;
collider.enabled = true;
}
```

and this is the player code

```
var score:int = 0;
var opScore:int = 0;
var sphereSettingsInstance:sphereSettings;

if(sphereSettingsInstance.OnTriggerEnter()){
score++;

}



function OnGUI () {
if(networkView.isMine){
   GUI.Label (Rect (10, 10, 100, 20), "Your score is: " + score);
   GUI.Label (Rect (100, 100, 200, 20), "Opponents score is: " + opScore);
    }


}
```

Comment: The unity tag is for Microsoft Unity. Please don't misuse it.

Answer (score 0):

You should see [Changing variables in another script](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/200262/changing-variables-in-another-script.html), so you will want to do this

```
function OnTriggerEnter(other : Collider){
Debug.Log("Trigger Entered");
renderer.enabled = false;
collider.isTrigger = false;
collider.enabled = false;
//yield WaitForSeconds ( Random.Range(1.0, 10.0));
yield WaitForSeconds (3);
renderer.enabled = true;
collider.isTrigger = true;
collider.enabled = true;
var : GameObject player = GameObject.Find("player");
var : script scriptB = player.GetComponent("scriptB");
scriptB.variable++;
}
```

But your counter will need to be a variable